# SvelteKit: Display chat stream tokens from Langchain

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, openai-api, chatgpt-api, langchain

I'm working on a project where I'm using SvelteKit and Langchain. I want to implement a feature where I can press a button and have the UI display the tokens of a chat stream as they come in. However, I'm facing some difficulties with my current implementation using form actions.

Here's what I have implemented so far:

In +page.server.ts:

```js
import type { Actions } from './$types';
import { OPENAI_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
import type { RequestEvent } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai"
import { HumanChatMessage } from 'langchain/schema';

const message = `Hello World!`

const model = new ChatOpenAI({
  openAIApiKey: OPENAI_API_KEY,
  streaming: true,
  modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  callbacks: [
    {
      handleLLMNewToken(token) {
        // Don't know what to do here
      },
    }
  ]
});

export const actions = {
  chat: async (event: RequestEvent) => {
    const msg = await model.call([new HumanChatMessage(message)])

    return {
      success: true,
      message: msg.text,
    }
  }
} satisfies Actions;
```

In +page.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
  export let form;
  $: response = form?.message;
</script>

<div>
  {#if response}
    {response}
  {/if}
</div>

<div>
  <form method="POST" action="?/chat" use:enhance>
    <button class="">
      Generate
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I need assistance in displaying the tokens from the chat stream as they come in. Specifically, I'm not sure how to handle the handleLLMNewToken callback in the Langchain ChatOpenAI model. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to take a look at this example repo from semicognitive on Github: https://github.com/semicognitive/sveltekit-chat. He uses the `CallbackManager` from Langchain in the context of creating and returning a `ReadableStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having right now a setup where I ask 4 different trained ollama models from the frontend. I get output, but also `not streamed` :(

Maybe my setup example helps:
I have this models:

```
dev ⍉ ➜ ollama list
NAME                        ID              SIZE    MODIFIED
codellama:latest            36893bf9bc7f    3.8 GB  5 days ago
llama2:latest               5c1a4ea68dd0    3.8 GB  4 days ago
llama2-uncensored:latest    ff4791cdfa68    3.8 GB  2 days ago
marketing:latest            c15276af8910    3.8 GB  3 days ago
php:latest                  97b961b10550    3.8 GB  21 hours ago
teacher:latest              7a495416771f    3.8 GB  3 days ago
```

Now with this +page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    /** @type {import('./$types').ActionData} */
    import { enhance } from "$app/forms";
    export let data;
    export let form: any;
    let loading = false;
    const roles = ["marketing", "teacher", "productManager", "researcher"];
    const modelResponse = roles.map((role) => {
        return {
            [role]: "",
        };
    });
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Query Form</h1>
    {#each roles as role}
        <form
            action="?/query"
            method="POST"
            class=""
            use:enhance={() => {
                loading = true;
                return async ({ result, update }) => {
                    loading = false;
                    console.log("result", result);
                    modelResponse[role] = result?.data;
                    await update({reset: false});
                };
            }}
        >
            {#if form?.missing}
                <p class="error">This field is required</p>
            {/if}
            {#if form?.success}
                <p class="success">Thanks for your submission!</p>
            {/if}

            <input name="role" type="hidden" value={role} />
            <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
                <label for={role} class="w-100 me-2"
                    >{role}
                    <input
                        class="form-control"
                        name="query"
                        type="text"
                        value="Why is the sky blue? Short answer"
                        id={role}
                    />
                </label>
                {#if loading}
                    <button disabled class="btn btn-primary px-4">
                        <div
                            class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                            role="status"
                        >
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                {:else}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                {/if}
            </div>
            {#if modelResponse[role]}
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label"
                        >Output</label
                    >
                    <textarea
                        class="form-control"
                        id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                        rows="3">{modelResponse[role]}</textarea
                    >
                </div>
            {/if}
        </form>
    {/each}
</div>
```

And this +page.server.ts

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Readable } from "stream"
import type { Actions } from './$types'

export const actions = {
    query: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData()
        const role = data.get('role')
        const query = data.get('query')
        console.log('Role:', role, ' Query:', query)
        try {
            const response = await axios.post<Readable>('http://127.0.0.1:11434/api/generate', {
                model: role, // must be one of custom generated llama2 models ["marketing", "teacher", "productManager", "researcher"]
                prompt: query,
                stream: true, //not working
                responseType: 'stream' //not working
            })

            const json = JSON.parse(("[" + response.data.replace(/\}/g, "},").replace(/\n/g, '') + "]").replace(",]", ']'))
            const plainModelResponse = json.reduce((acc, j) => acc + (j.response ? j.response : ""), "").trim()
            console.log('plainModelResponse', plainModelResponse)
            return plainModelResponse

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
} satisfies Actions
```

I get output in the frontend from those specified models, but not streamed over the api.